# How can I immediately see the changed data on my JTable?

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, actionlistener

I have already used the fireDataChanged methods but I think due to the fact that this is connected to my database it will not do anything.

```
    DelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int selRow = table.getSelectedRow();            
            Object element = table.getValueAt(selRow, 0);
            th = table.getTableHeader();
            tcm = th.getColumnModel();
            Statement statement = null;
            try {
                statement = ResultSetTableModelFactory.connection
                        .createStatement();


                    if (JisSelected == true) {

                        String delete = "DELETE FROM J WHERE JNO = '" + element + "';";
                        statement.executeUpdate(delete);
                    }
                     if (SPJisSelected == true) {

                        String delete = "DELETE FROM SPJ WHERE SNO = '" + element + "';";
                        statement.executeUpdate(delete);

                    }
                System.out.println(element);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            model.fireTableDataChanged();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ActionListener` should perform its work in your implementation of the `doInBbackground()` method of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). In the interim, you should signify that the operation is pending in whatever way is appropriate to your application, perhaps in a renderer or status indicator. If the database operation succeeds, update the `TableModel` in your implementation of `done()`. In no case should you invoke `fireTableDataChanged()` except from within the model.